# Piping popen stderr and stdout

Tags: python

I want to call scripts from a directory (they are executable shell scripts) via python.

so far so good:

```
    for script in sorted(os.listdir(initdir), reverse=reverse):
        if script.endswith('.*~') or script == 'README':
             continue
        if os.access(script, os.X_OK):
            try:
                execute = os.path.abspath(script)
                sp.Popen((execute, 'stop' if reverse else 'start'),
                         stdin=None, stderr=sp.PIPE,
                         stdout=sp.stderr, shell=True).communicate()
            except:
                raise
```

Now what i Want is: lets say i have a bash script with a start functiont. from which I call

> echo "Something"

Now I want to see that echo on sys.stdout and the exit Code. I believe you do this with .communicate() but mine doesn't work the way i thought it would.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Confer http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html.

> communicate() returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata).

After the subprocess has finished, you can get the return code from the Popen instance:

> Popen.returncode: The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and indirectly by communicate()).

Likewise, you can achieve your goals like that:

```
sp = subprocess.Popen([executable, arg1, arg2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = sp.communicate()
if out:
    print "standard output of subprocess:"
    print out
if err:
    print "standard error of subprocess:"
    print err
print "returncode of subprocess:"
print sp.returncode
```

By the way, I would change the test

```
    if script.endswith('.*~') or script == 'README':
         continue
```

into a positive one:

```
if not filename.endswith(".sh"):
    continue
```

It is better to be explicit about what you would like to execute than being explicit about what you do *not* want to execute.

Also, you should name your variables in a more general fashion, so `script` should be `filename` in the first place. As `listdir` also lists directories, you can explicitly check for those. Your current `try/except` block is not proper as long as you do not handle a specific exception. Instead of `abspath`, you should just concatenate `initdir` and `filename`, which is a concept often applied in context of `os.listdir()`. For security reasons, use `shell=True` in the constructor of the `Popen` object only if you are absolutely sure that you require it. Let me suggest the following:

```
for filename in sorted(os.listdir(initdir), reverse=reverse):
    if os.path.isdir(filename) or not filename.endswith(".sh"):
         continue
    if os.access(script, os.X_OK):
        exepath = os.path.join(initdir, filename)
        sp = subprocess.Popen(
            (exepath, 'stop' if reverse else 'start'),
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = sp.communicate()
        print out, err, sp.returncode
```

Comment: Yeah, i have specific exceptions I just didn't type them in because thy are not relevant to the question. But you are correct about the variable names, I always struggle with proper names so Thanks again