# Python Popen process not working when it is executed from init.d script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, popen, init.d

I have a script stored in /etc/init.d that works ok when executed at boot time. Since I do not export USER, it should execute everything as root (if I'm not wrong).

Then, it executes python3 script.py
In this script, everything works fine until it reaches

```
espeak_process = Popen(["espeak", "-ves", "-s100", msg, "--stdout"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
aplay_process = Popen(["aplay", "-D", "sysdefault"], stdin=espeak_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

EDIT: changed for this code, but the created file is empty

```
def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    f = open('/home/pi/debug_err.txt', 'w')
    f.write('hi ')
    f.write(ex_cls+' '+ex+' '+tb)
    f.close()

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
espeak_process = Popen(["espeak", "-ves", "-s100", msg, "--stdout"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

/EDIT

At which point it stops. I can tell that since it writes a debug file before and after this step, and the 2nd one is never written.

The thing though is that if I execute in a terminal

```
sudo sh /etc/init.d/begin start
```

Then the "python3 script.py" is executed entirely ok, including the Popen part.

Why is that happening?
Thx

(init.d script)

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/begin 

#USER=pi
HOME=/home/pi

#export USER HOME
export HOME

case "$1" in
 start)
  if [ -f "/home/pi/begin.pid" ];
  then
    kill -9 $(cat /home/pi/begin.pid)
    rm -f /home/pi/begin.pid
  fi
  python3 /home/pi/script.py &
  ;;

 stop)
  kill -9 $(cat /home/pi/begin.pid)
  rm -f /home/pi/begin.pid
  ;;

 *)
  echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/begin {start|stop}"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Can you try reading `stderr` and perhaps log the output?

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10683323/948550

Comment: Thanks. Based on your link I've tried to recover the error message with communicate() but the python script stops when it executes it, so it never reaches this code. Is there a way that I can handle this?

Comment: [The python script exits before executing the "communicate()" command, so I cannot read any error message]

Comment: unrelated: you should add `close_fds=True` (it is default on POSIX since some Python 3 version) and set all (stdin/stdout/stderr) unused streams to `DEVNULL` e.g., `stdin=DEVNULL`. Call `espeak_process.stdout.close()` after `Popen(["aplay...` Either read from `aplay_process.stdout` or set `stdout=DEVNULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Popen()` returns as soon as the child process is started. It does not wait for it to finish. It is very unlikely that your scripts blocks for long on `Popen()`.

A possible explanation is that your script raises an exception and terminates while trying to start `espeak` or `aplay` processes -- that is why you don't see the 2nd record in the log file. Catch and log all errors e.g., set [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook).

You don't see the error when running manually because the environment is different: disks are mounted, audio service is running, X is started, etc -- I don't know what `espeak`, `aplay` require to run.

As an alternative save all output to a file:

```
# python3 /home/pi/script.py </dev/null >/home/pi/script.out 2>/home/pi/script.err &
```

---

> I can see what's the problem, and it was to pass an argument with accentuated words (strange that it wasn't the case when I executed the script from the shell). I've eliminated the accents and now it works ok.

Try to specify a utf-8 locale. The default is C locale that uses ascii encoding that can't represent accentuated words directly:

```
# LANG=C.UTF-8 python3 ...
```

If there is no `C.UTF-8` locale in the output of `locale -a` command then choose any other utf-8 locale from the list.

Comment: I have added the code (see edited question), and the log file is written but it is empty, any idea?

Comment: @Gerard: I see errors in  `log_uncaught_exceptions()`. You should test it first on a simple script that intentionally raises an exception. I've update the answer. You could redirect the output of the script as an alternative

Comment: The problem is that when I execute the script (and I can see any message on the shell) everything runs ok (or at least I hear sound and the script does what he has to do).

Comment: But when it runs from the init.d script, then it fails, and then I cannot see any error message

Comment: Actually, I can see that it writes "hi" (see edited question), but it doesn't write anything else. How is that possible? How can I know why the script is stopping there?

Comment: @Gerard: Have you tried your `excepthook` with a dead simple script to make sure it works as I suggested? Have you tried to redirect the output to a file as I suggested?

Comment: Ah, you meant to test the excepthook, not the script, I didn't get that. I'll try asap. But related to the output redirection, now I see that I can do that in the init.d script as well, again I didn't get it. I'll try asap too

Comment: Yes, by redirecting the output as you say (I have not tested excepthook) I can see what's the problem, and it was to pass an argument with accentuated words (strange that it wasn't the case when I executed the script from the shell). I've eliminated the accents and now it works ok. Thanks!

Comment: @Gerard: your `excepthook` tries to add string with non strings, use formatting instead or: `f.write(" ".join(map(repr, [ex_cls, ex, tb])))` I've updated the answer to show how to enable support for accentuated words.