# Suppressing the output of tcpdump completely

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, tcpdump

I'm writing a python script that executes tcpdump through subprocess.open

Now, I want this script to not output anything to the screen(stdout), but just run silently. I've tried doing this:

```
ps_dump = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump', '-U', '-w', pcapfile, 'port 53'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But it still outputs these:

---

device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes

0 packets captured

0 packets received by filter

0 packets dropped by kernel

device eth0 left promiscuous mode

---

I want to completely suppress these. If i run the script it shouldn't print anything. 
I read that you can suppress in linux using >/dev/null but how do I use it in the Popen command above?

Any suggestions or answer as to how to get this to work?

Comment: I think @λuser has it right - tcpdump is writing to stderr and you aren't capturing that output. For more information see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683184/piping-popen-stderr-and-stdout

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a file descriptor to the `stdout=` argument, so simply:

```
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as nullfd:
    proc = Popen(..., stdout=nullfd)
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to work... I tried it before asking this question

Comment: @vinwin It does work on my computer with a command like `ls`. Are you sure `tcpdump` doesn't output on stderr?