# How to catch subprocess output outside the subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to achieve this:

```
def x():
 subprocess.Popen(...)
```

I cannot modify `x()` however I need to reach (suppress) `stderr` / `stdout` of the `Popen` call inside.

I need something like:

```
with suppress_subprocess:
 x()
```

...or something like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683184/piping-popen-stderr-and-stdout

Comment: Have a look at python decorators @vpas

Comment: Please give me more help, and please note the inside of x() function cannot be modified!

Comment: Is it cheating to alter `x`'s globals to find another `subprocess`?

Answer (score 0):

return from your x function the popen object and then just access him from your caller file like so:

```
def x():
     return subprocess.Popen(...)


p= x()

print p.stdout
print p.stderr
print p.returncode
```

etc ....

Comment: As I said: x() function cannot be modified, let's say it's 3rd party code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct and easy way. You would have to determine the PID of the subprocess and mess with its UNIX file descriptors, from another thread. Messy.

Comment: By the time you could find the PID, it's too late: you're racing with its (first) output.

Answer (score 0):

Sine

> ... I need to reach (suppress) `stderr` / `stdout` ...

have you tried the approach described here [Silence the stdout of a function in Python without trashing sys.stdout and restoring each function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2828953/4183498)?

In your case it can be something like

```
import io
import sys

save_stdout = sys.stdout


suppress_stdout():
    try:
        sys.stdout = io.BytesIO()
        x()
    finally:
        sys.stdout = save_stdout
```