# Capturing INFO/DEBUG outputs from system commands in Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to run a python app within my Python script via CLI, the python app returns a few output lines that look similar to this:

```
Using folder: /home/pi/Downloads/
INFO:ytdl:Generating queue item for: https://youtube.com/11223344
ERROR:ytdl: Wrong URL: No video data
All done!
```

In my python script I run a command like this:

```
out = os.popen("ytdl https://youtube.com/11223344").read()
```

I was hoping I could capture the whole output, but it appears to only capture the following:

```
Using folder: /home/pi/Downloads/
All done!
```

Does anyone know how I can capture *all* the output? The end goal really is to check to see if there is any `ERROR` debug lines in the response... if there is then it should return a **true/false** value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Piping popen stderr and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683184/piping-popen-stderr-and-stdout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in, out = os.popen4("ytdl https://youtube.com/11223344").read()
```

Please use peopn4 where out captures stderr in addition to stdout. You may also read about popen3 as follows to capture stderr separately from stdout

```
in, out, err = os.popen3("ytdl https://youtube.com/11223344").read()
```