# How to receive ERRORS when running command on CMD using os.popen

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

I'm using os.popen() method to run commands on cmd and get response with .read().
When I'm encountering an ERROR, the read returns '' and the output just printed.
For Example -

```
exit_code = popen("taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F").read()
print(exit_code)
# When Chrome closed
>>> ERROR: The process "chrome.exe" not found.
>>> ''
```

How can I get this ERROR in my exit_code variable?

Comment: Try `exit_code = os.popen("taskkill /IM Xchrome.exe /F 2>&1").read()` (I use an imaginary _imagename_). You can use `2>&1` because `os.popen` runs argument in the `cmd /C` context in Windows…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10683323/447901